# use exported component in other file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my abc.js I have splitted component

```
export const BlockA = () => <div>Block A</div>
export const BlockB = () => <div>Block B</div>

const ABCComponent = () => (
    <div>
       <BlockA/>
       <BlockB/>
    </div>
)
export default ABCComponent
```

then in another file, says it's xyz.js I want to use BlockA component from abc.js, I do

`import { BlockA } from './abc.js'` I got error of `...does not contain an export named 'BlockA'.`? Any clue why?

Comment: I just tried it and it works at least in a `create-react-app` project. Maybe this has to do with your Babel config.

Comment: not sure how your build steps looks like but try removing `.js` suffix from path you import (`import { BlockA } from './abc'`)